# Adding another gas line for a new gas range

Tags: appliances

I’m planning to change our electric range to a gas range.  On our basement level I’ve got the 1” main gas line in.  There are two Tees, both 3/4”.  One goes to the water heater and the other to the forced air furnace.

I would rather not add a 3rd Tee to branch off the main 1” line to go to the upstairs for the stove.  Can I Tee off the water heater line or would it cause a low pressure issue?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: What is the type and size of the water heater? If it is a 40 or 50-gal tank with a 40,000 BTU/h burner, then I think you might be able to share the 3/4" line. It also depends on the length of  the shared portion of the 3/4" line.  Look at the specifications on the gas range and see how much gas it is supposed to need. There are tables that will give how much gas can be transported through a given diameter pipe of a given length (at standard residential pressure of 7 inch water column or 0.25 psi), but it seems to me that pipes in practice can carry more.

Comment: Gas plumbing in an urban setting is highly regulated and not a DIY project unless one is experienced and capable. You will almost certainly be hiring a licensed gas plumber and getting a permit. What you need to know is how to hire a plumber who knows what he is doing. In case you don't know, the usual units of gas flow for appliances and the piping that supplies them is BTU/h and not the units of volume (e.g., cubic ft) that the gas company uses for billing.

Comment: @JimStewart Appliances are rated in BTU (because that is what you are trying to do - produce heat) and gas companies bill in cubic feet (because that is what you measure with a gas meter) or in Therms. But while there is some variation depending on the particular mix of gas, Cubic Feet -> Therm -> BTU actually varies over a relatively small range (pun intended) - according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekatherm varies from 975 to 1,100 BTU/CF. So for practical purposes 1,000 BTU/CF is a good enough (and easy to calculate) average.

Comment: Just to give some background on myself.  Even though I haven’t worked in the field for about 10 years.  I’m a Chief Engineer level maintenance person.  I’ve stubbed out a few stoves (not many), but I’ve done this on commercial grade stoves in a hotel environment.  I’ve already got everything scoped out.

Comment: The addon would be within the 1st foot (more like 4-6” of the 1” on the 3/4” run to the water heater.  The total load on the pipe with combined tasks is 17 feet.  The individual runs are:  1” to water heater 10 feet.  Run from 3/4 tie in to stove 7 feet.  I just wonder if the brief restriction within the 1st foot off the main would make any significant difference?

Comment: https://support.eccotemp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012918108-Gas-Pipe-System-Sizing

Comment: This contains a chart.  Based on the systems setup.  I believe I can branch off the 3/4” and be good.

Comment: If you are inserting a Tee in the 3/4" line at 4-6" from the 1" line, there should be very little pressure drop in that 4-6" of  3/4" line that supplies *both* the WH and the range, so it should be "almost" as good as Teeing off the 1" line itself. Is this gas range one that uses gas for the surface burners but electricity for the oven? Will you be doing the work yourself? Are you required to get a permit?

Comment: Total BTU’s/hr combined 121500.  40000 got water heater.  81500 for the range.  My piping distances are much shorter.  And the chart shows 2 1/2” lines coming off a 3/4” branch off of a 1 1/4” main truck.  We have a gas dryer on another branch further down.  And a furnace at 100,000 btu/hr input.  But our total is 221,500 btu total at our house.  No gas log.